# HTML5 canvas produces black/white images

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am working on a small Linux based device with a monochrome screen. I would like to use a Webkit browser to render local images to a canvas. My goal was to get the base-64 encoded data and post it to a form somewhere on the internet. It works, but all images ended up being black and white. I can imagine since the device renders it monochrome it will produce monochrome imagedata. But I can't find a way to calculate the context it in color (but seeing it in b/w). Anyone?

Code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');                                                       
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');                                                                    
var imageObj = new Image();                                                                               

imageObj.onload = function() {                                                                             
    if(imageObj.width < imageObj.height){                                                                
        canvas.width = 768;                                                                          
        canvas.height = 1024;                                                                        
    }                                                                                                    
    else{                                                                                                
        canvas.width = 1024;                                                                         
        canvas.height = 768;                                                                         
    }                                                                                                    
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');                                                                     
    context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);                                        


    document.getElementById('myInput').value = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');                               
};                                                                                                         
imageObj.src = 'pathToImage';
```

Thanks for any reponses!

Comment: R-PI? Could you do a small test, to see what length you're getting with `console.log(context.createImageData(1, 1).data.length);` It should say 4. And also try to export image as image/png..

Comment: *I am working on a small Linux based device with a monochrome screen* (...) *but all images ended up being black and white.* --- Have you slept in the last 48 hours? (unfortunate edit)

Comment: @Ken, it's a Kindle, and the data.length call returns 16. I am guessing the device has a 16-bit grayscale framebuffer. I have tried png, no differences. I was hoping there is a way to initialize the context or canvas with a different color-depth, but until now I can't seem to find a way to do that.
Yaroslav, yes I have. Should have added the word 'uploaded'.

Comment: I bet you'll have to handle the image as a binary (using an XMLHttpRequest rather than img.src =.... ) , and encode in Base64 by yourself, since the canvas will always match the color space of your device. See http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#color-spaces-and-color-correction  and  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Base64_encoding_and_decoding

Comment: @GameAlchemist, I have to access a resource using the file protocol (but also from an html document loaded using the file protocol), so I'm guessing I can't do a XMLHttpRequest there, due to security reasons. Also the canvas is kind enough to take care the resizing of the image for me. I probably have to redo the whole thing and find another way to access the images or their base64 representation in a browser.

Comment: 1) You sure you cannot get access to the blob of the file ? 2) if the resize is by an integer ratio, computations are pretty straightforward.

Comment: Will try the XMLHttpRequest to the file protocol tonight. Will post my results.

Comment: If it returns 16 then something is very wrong, probably an issue with the browser on the device (which I was getting at initially). Canvas only supports RGBA (24bit + 8bit alpha channel) as per specs, or 4 bytes if you will. It should have returned 4 in all cases. If 16 bytes that is like 32-bits per channel. A 16 color image would in general only need a nibble size (or actually less, only 3 bits) or 1 byte depending on packing (images with palette/color indexes uses bit-planes in any case, but canvas no). Could you set up a fiddle for us so we can more context?

Comment: No luck with the XMLHttpRequest using the file protocol. Next attempt will be a step down in the protocol layer; when the image is uploaded to the device (local network by the way, no internet connectivity) through scp I can base64 encode the file and embed it in the html file. Feels a bit ugly, but it will probably work.
@Ken, I can set up a fiddle, but it will be inpossible to test, since it only fails on the device, not in a browser on laptops/phones. Only Kindle. I will try to figure out the unix framebuffer configuration too.